# Why Can't I See Classes in .net 2010 Web Service?

Tags: web-services, web, asmx, asp.net-1.1

In .net 2010 I have a fairly simple class with 1 function I need to expose through a web service. It uses several basic custom classes which the consumer would, in theory, populate with data and send back to me. The problem is, after I create a WebService and then try to consume the service, it only sees the function and the two top level classes that are mentioned in the function. None of the classes that make properties of the top level classes are available.

I've done this in vs 2005 and the proxy would generate a reference.vb file that would spell out that classes used. But I don't see that file in 2010.

Here is an example. Below the main class Application is availble to the proxy, but none of its property classes are.

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class Income
    Public Property monthly() As Integer
    Public Property wages() As Integer
    Public Property taxableInterest() As Integer
    Public Property taxExemptInterest() As Integer
    Public Property taxableRefunds() As Integer
    Public Property alimony() As Integer
    Public Property capitalGains() As Integer
    Public Property pensions() As Integer
    Public Property farmIncome() As Integer
    Public Property unemployment() As Integer
    Public Property other() As Integer
    Public Property MAGIDeductions() As Integer
End Class
<Serializable()> _
Public Class Applicant

    Public Sub New()
        _relationships = New ArrayList 
        _income = New Income
    End Sub

    Public Property isApplicant() As String
    Public Property disabled() As String
    Public Property student() As String
    Public Property eligible() As String
    Public Property incarcerated() As String
    Public Property livesInState() As String
    Public Property claimedByNonApplicant() As String
    Public Property longTermCare() As String
    Public Property hasInsurance() As String
    Public Property stateEmployeeHealthBenefits() As String
    Public Property priorInsuranceIndicator() As String
    Public Property pregnant() As String
    Public Property pregnantThreeMonths() As String
    Public Property formerlyFosterCare() As String
    Public Property incomeTaxesRequired() As String
    Public Property citizen() As String
    Public Property id() As String
    Public Property age() As Int32
    Public Property hours() As Int32
    Public Property temporarilyOutOfState As String
    Public Property noFixedAddress As String
    Public Property claimerIsOutOfState As String
    Public Property endDate As String
    Public Property numberOfChildrenExpected As String
    Public Property hadMedicaid As String
    Public Property ageLeftFosterCare As String
    Public Property state As String
    Public Property legalPermanentResident As String
    Public Property lawful As String
    Public Property fiveYearBar As String
    Public Property fortyQuarters As String
    Public Property fiveYearBarMet As String
    Public Property refugeeMedicalAssistanceEligible As String
    Public Property humanTraffickingVictim As String
    Public Property startDate As String
    Public Property qualified As String
    Public Property deportWithheldDate As String
    Public Property entryDate As String
    Public Property statusGrantDate As String
    Public Property income() As Income
    Public Property relationships() As ArrayList 
End Class
<Serializable()> _
Public Class Resident 
    Public Property id() As String
End Class
<Serializable()> _
Public Class Household
    Public Sub New()
        _People = New ArrayList 
    End Sub
    Public Property HouseholdID() As String
    Public Property People() As ArrayList 
End Class
<Serializable()> _
Public Class Filer
    Public Property id() As String
End Class
<Serializable()> _
Public Class taxReturn
    Public Sub New()
        _Filers = New ArrayList 
        _Dependents = New ArrayList 
    End Sub
    Private _Filers As ArrayList 
    Private _Dependents As ArrayList 
    Public Property Filers() As ArrayList 
        Get
            Return _Filers
        End Get
        Set(value As ArrayList) 
            _Filers = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Dependents() As ArrayList 
        Get
            Return _Dependents
        End Get
        Set(value As ArrayList) 
            _Dependents = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
<Serializable()> _
Public Class Application

    Public Sub New()
        _People = New ArrayList 
        _PhysicalHouseholds = New ArrayList 
        _TaxReturns = New ArrayList
    End Sub

    Private _applicationID As String = "TEST

    Public Property State() As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _applicationID
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _applicationID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property People() As ArrayList 
    Public Property PhysicalHouseholds() As ArrayList 
    Public Property TaxReturns() As ArrayList 

End Class
```

Comment: From your use of the obsolete `ArrayList` class, may I presume that you are using the obsolete ASMX web service technology?

Comment: You may presume. The guy who needs to hit the service is using .net 1.1. So I am trying to make this service as accessable as I can. It occurs to me there may be a problem passing ArrayLists through services.

Comment: Those would have been relevant tags. There might well be issues with `ArrayList`. That is effectively a list of `object`, where it is not known ahead of time what kind of `object`.